# VS Code: Can't load anaconda environment on Python Interactive

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I am using VS Code in Windows 10.
I am able to use the dependencies in my conda environment if I Run the Python Script in Terminal. However, I am not able to use the environment in the Python Interactive shell.

For instance, I am using my `datascience`environment which has the package `fuzzywuzzy`. I have included the env path into the `settings.json`as the `python.pythonPath`. But the Python version used in the Jupyter Notebook is the default anaconda base `C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe`

[image]

What is also extrange, is that if I run `!conda list` within the Notebook, I can see the `fuzzywuzzy` package.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is jupyter installed in the datascience environment? Also what is your setting for Python: Data Science: Search for jupyter? (You can check this in your settings (Ctrl + ,)

Comment: I did not have Jupyter installed in the environment. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer on the Interactive Windows. Priyatham has already pointed you in the right direction. Currently our Window tries to use the currently selected environment (the one in the lower left corner). But we didn't want to totally block customers if they didn't have Jupyter installed in each environment. So if the selected interpreter doesn't have Jupyter in the environment we'll check other environments on the system, looking for the closest python version match to the currently selected one. If we find something with Jupyter we'll launch the Interactive Window using that. In this case we do show a popup in the lower right indicating that we didn't find Jupyter and that we are falling back on a different environment, but this message can be pretty easy to miss.

Comment: Additionally, I have now installed anaconda3 on my Windows Subsystem for Linux. Is there any way to tell Jupyter to use the environments from there? Can I add a path to my home/username/anaconda3/bin ? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Pablo. So currently you can't connect windows VS Code to an anaconda in WSL. Even if you have the path it would try to do a windows activation on that environment, which would not work. You can use VSCode's WSL remote support, but that would actually be running all of your code on the WSL, which I'm not sure if that's what you want or not:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl