# Visual Studio Code Python Interactive Window env different from selected?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

[image]I am using visual studio code to try and replace the Spyder IDE. To replicate Spyder's variable explorer, I am trying to leverage VS code's Python Interactive Window.

Upon launching Vs Code, I select my environment using "Select Interpreter" and then picking the env. This then changes at the bottom of the application as expected.

However, when I then try and run my code in the interactive window it appears to reference a different environment? It also keeps telling me to install ipykernel.

Is this functioning correctly? I do see an option to change the env in the interactive window but that doesn't do anything.enter image description here

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538270/vs-code-cant-load-anaconda-environment-on-python-interactive) But I have ipykernel installed in my environment so I'm not sure why it wouldn't notice that? Is there another dependency?

Comment: How did you create the environment? Is it with Anaconda or venv for example ?

Comment: @GustavRasmussen it is an anaconda environment. Created in anaconda prompt.

Comment: @rcwilkin1993 I'm a developer on this extension. If you can could you go to Help -> Toggle Developer Tools in VSCode when you try to start the interactive window. Then from that window in the "Console" tab, right click and save it as a file. If you post that file here I could take a look to see what might be going on.

Comment: @Ian Huff. Unfortunately I can’t send it as it may contain secured information (albeit a small amount). Do you have any other advice? I’m also stuck in the ipykernel loop where it is constantly asking me to install that every time

Comment: Sure I get that those logs can't always be shared. One thing that you could try is to get one anaconda environment totally configured with what you need to run. Then also install jupyter into that environment. Then if you use the command "Python: Select interpreter to start Jupyter server" select that interpreter. Also have it selected in the bottom left of the UI. That might help with the launch issues. What I think is currently happening is that a different interpreter is selected for jupyter launch and it's having trouble switching to the interpreter that you have selected.

Comment: Thanks @IanHuff, I have spent a long time trying to get this up and running. That specific environment also has jupyter installed. Upon running the Jupyter server it still did not work. I keep getting that "ipykernel" not installed error that apparently might an issue on an older version?

Comment: Could you share a "conda list" from that environment? Just so I can see what versions are installed?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we can simplify the problem.
Click top-right environment and changes it to which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Start off by opening your Anaconda prompt and from there activate your virtual environment (type: conda activate my_env, replacing my_env with your environment name, and hit enter.)
Then type the command: 'code', which will open up VS Code from within your active virtual environment. Before this approach, also check that your VS Code settings.json file has the python path set correctly to your environment installation. Now it should work.
To see your install path: Anaconda is installed in your user home directory: Windows 10: C:\Users\\Anaconda3\

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. I do not have a problem activating a conda env or launching it in VS Code. The problem comes when I select the "Run Current File in Python Interactive Window." It then references a different environment